# jQuery .On() not firing with parameters passed from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Working on a Chrome extension and the .On() callback isn't firing and the click event isn't being attached to the elements as it should be.  Console isn't showing any errors and debugging show that all the right values are being passed to the inital .On() call.  Not sure what is tripping it up.

```
var handlers = {

  'startButton': {
    'parent': 'body',
    'type': 'click',
    'id': '#startButton',
    'needsIf': true,
    'ifCondition': function(){
      return $('#selectSite').val() != 0;
    },
    'elseDo': function(){
      alert("You must select a site to poll");
    },
    'message': {
      'index': 'openTabUrl',
      'value': function(){        
        return $('#selectSite').val();
      }
    }
  },

  'stopButton': {
    'parent': 'body',
    'type': 'click',
    'id': '#stopButton',    
    'needsIf': false,
    'message': {    
      'index': 'closeTab',
      'value': true,
    },
    'action': window.showStartButton  
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){  
  for (var key in handlers) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + handlers[key].parent);
    $(handlers[key].parent).on(handlers[key].type, handlers[key].id, function(){
      console.log("test during " + key);
      if (handlers[key].needsIf){
        if (handlers[key].ifCondition()){
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage(handlers[key].message);
        } else {    
          handlers[key].elseDo();
        }
      } else {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(handlers[key].message);
        if(handlers[key].action){
          handlers[key].action();
        }
      }
      return false;
    });    
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in fact that during `click` handler `key` points to last key in `handlers`, not to current one. So, as some kind of workaround, you can use:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g9ua0qy/).

```
$(handlers[key].parent).on(handlers[key].type, handlers[key].id, function() {
    var handler;
    for (var k in handlers)
    {
        if (handlers[k].id == '#' + this.id)
        {
            handler = handlers[k];
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log("test during " + handler.id);
    if (handler.needsIf) {
        if (handler.ifCondition()) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(handler.message);
        } else {    
            handler.elseDo();
        }
    } else {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(handler.message);
        if (handler.action) {
            handler.action();
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It isn't executing the .On() statement at all though.  As soon as it hits that line it immediately restarts the for loop without executing any of the code in the callback.  Console output ends up just being `startButton -> body
popup.js:74 stopButton -> body
popup.js:74`

Comment: @Ryan it will not be executed immediately, because you hang `click` event handlers for elements. Code inside handler will be executed during element's clicking. Just click at "start" button or at "stop" button and you will see.

Comment: Okay, sorry, now I understand.  I didn't understand what your solution was doing, but that makes sense now.  It has to match the correct property when the click event happens to the one established when the click event was hung.  Your answer has fixed my problem, thanks!

Comment: @Ryan yes, it's all about matching the correct property (handler), other your code in fiddle remains "as is". You're welcome.